# Invoking google Map

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using the following code to invoke Google map in my simulator. i have already installed Google map in my simulator.

```
int mh = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");
        if(mh > 0) {
    try{
URLEncodedPostData uepd = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
uepd.append("action","LOCN");
uepd.append("a", "@latlon:"+lat+","+log);
uepd.append("title","Stanford University School of Medicin");
uepd.append("description", "XYZ");
String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?"+uepd.toString() };
ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e+"Excepton");
}}}
```

but i am getting a white screen , when i am pressing the menu button RUN GMAPS option is their. but when i am pressing the RUN GMAPS then also result is same only white screen is coming. i don't why it is coming. some one please help me out

i also want to Know. how to pin multiple places in google map.

thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you to use BlackBerry Maps, has is uses a lot less bandwidth than Google maps.

Comment: your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @Vivart is right, the above code also **[worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977201/bing-maps-sdk-for-blackberry-6-0/9987588#9987588)**. You can also consider using [BlackBerry Maps](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1181/GPS%20and%20BlackBerry%20Maps%20Development%20Guide.pdf) as [Michael B.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/83253/michael-b) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use kml file.

```
BrowserSession visit = Browser.getDefaultSession();
visit.displayPage("http://www.geochemie.uni-bremen.de/kml/borabora.kml");
```

you can test on simulator also.