# Using here maps in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, here-api

Can i use Here Maps 
http://here.com/, 
in blackberry RIM version 5.0 and above development?
Because i have an application which gets the user location and i need to put 2 pins on the map and get the distance between them , and the client wants Here maps.

I used bing map lately, but i need here map now.
[Bing Maps SDK For Blackberry 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977201/bing-maps-sdk-for-blackberry-6-0/9987588#9987588)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1) Use the Maps API for Java ME with the Blackberry JDK**

There is no native Maps API marketed for Blackberry, however the [Maps API for Asha](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/index.html) is a general **Java ME API**, whose only dependencies are **CLDC1.1** and **MIDP2.0**, so there is no reason why it shouldn't work with the Blackberry JDE. This article describes the [similarities](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Porting_from_BlackBerry_to_Series_40#Adding_maps_to_User_Interface_example).

There are a series of [code examples](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/HERE_Maps_Java_ME/code-examples.html) available which should work out of the box, except for one thing - you'll need to get hold of the jar files which usually reside in

```
C:/Nokia/Devices/Nokia_Asha_SDK_1_0/plugins/maps api/lib/
```

which can be obtained from the [Nokia Asha SDK](https://developer.nokia.com/asha).

So all you'll need to do is download the SDK, extract the file `maps-core.jar` or any of the other packages you want and access them as external JAR dependencies in the usual manner. See the examples on [github](https://github.com/nokia-developer/here-maps-component-demos/) for an idea of the capabilities of the library.

**Option 2) Use the Map Image API with the low level i/o**

Now, if all you need is a **single** "quick and dirty map", you can make a series of http calls to `m.nokia.me` using `javax.microedition.io` to get a map on screen. This article explains why using a static map is [probably a bad idea](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Using_the_RESTful_Map_API_with_Java_ME), but it would be a simple solution.

**Option 3) Create a cross-platform HTML5 app using Cordova or Web Apps**

This would be where the [Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis) would be useful,

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation , i will try one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you would visit the [developer.here.com](http://developer.here.com/native-apis) native APIs section, you could see that there is no offering for Blackberry.

Anyway, thus, if you really want to use HERE maps with the platform, you should check out the [Javascript API](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis)